# flask jinjaテンプレート内での制御文エラーについて

Tags: python, python3, html5, flask

flaskでページネーションの実装をおこなっていましたが、
どうしても、下記のエラーが解決できません。

user_maintenance.html内のfor文やif文のブロックに問題があるようですが、
{% endfor %}や{% endif %}はじっかりとfor文、if文に対応できていると思っております。
エラー文の
**閉じる必要がある最も内側のブロックは「for」です。**
という箇所も、しっかりと、for文は、閉じております。

この様なエラーで、他に確認すべきこと、解決策をご教示いただければと思います。

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: 不明なタグ 'endblock' が見つかりました。あなたはおそらく入れ子の間違いを犯しました。Jinja はこのタグを期待していますが、現在 'endfor' または 'else' を探しています。閉じる必要がある最も内側のブロックは「for」です。
```

```py
# app.py

@app.route('/user_maintenance')
def user_maintenance():

    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    users = User.query.order_by(User.id).paginate(page=page, per_page=10)
    return render_template('user_maintenance.html', users=users)
```

```html
<!-- user_maintenance.html -->

    <nav class="my-2" aria-label="Page navigation">
        <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
          <li {% if users.has_prev %}class="page-item"{% else %} class="page-item disabled"{% endif %}><a class="page-link" href="{% if users.has_prev %}{{ url_for('user_maintenance', page=users.prev_num) }}{% else %}#{% endif %}">前へ</a></li>

    
          {% for page_num in users.iter_pages(left_edge=1, right_edge=1, left_current=1, right_current=2) %}  
            {% if page_num %}
                {% if users.page == page_num %}
                    <li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link" href="#">{{ page_num }}</a></li>
                {% else %}
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="{{ url_for('user_maintenance', page=page_num) }}">{{ page_num }}</a></li>
                {% endif %}
            {% else %}
                <li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link" href="#">&hellip;</a></li>
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}

          <li {% if users.has_next %}class="page-item"{% else %} class="page-item disabled"{% endif %}><a class="page-link" href="{% if users.has_next %}{{ url_for('user_maintenance', page=users.next_num) }}{% else %}#{% endif %}">次へ</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

Comment: こんなツールなどで調べられれば何か参考になるかもしれません。[motet-a/jinjalint](https://github.com/motet-a/jinjalint), [Jinja Template Linter and Formatter](https://www.djlint.com/docs/languages/jinja/)

Comment: <!-- {% for user in users %} -->を{# {% for user in users %} #}とする必要がありました。jinjaテンプレート内でのコメント方法に誤りがあったためです。

Comment: 解決したならその内容詳細を自己回答にしてみてください。